# Components on the JMenuBar

Tags: java, graphics, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I am looking for a way to change the graphics of a component on a `JMenuBar`

I have the following `JMenuBar`.

```
package GUIMain;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyMenuBar extends JMenuBar
{
    int fontMetrics;
    FontMetrics fM;
    
    JLabel lblSmartSize = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JCheckBox chkbtnSmartSize = new JCheckBox();
    
    SortsGui sG;
    
    public MyMenuBar(SortsGui sG)
    {
        this.sG = sG;
        setBorderPainted(true);
        makePopUpMenu();
    }
    
    void makePopUpMenu()
    {
        add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        
        fM = lblSmartSize.getFontMetrics(lblSmartSize.getFont());
        fontMetrics = fM.stringWidth("Enable Smart Resizing?");
        lblSmartSize.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(fontMetrics+10,25));
        lblSmartSize.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fontMetrics+10,25));
        lblSmartSize.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(fontMetrics+10,25));
        add(lblSmartSize);
        
        chkbtnSmartSize.setBackground(lblSmartSize.getBackground());
        add(chkbtnSmartSize);
    }
}
```

This creates a `JMenuBar` which looks like this (apologies for blown up screenshot)
[image: Shows picture of the menu bar]

As you can see the `JMenuBar` has a `JLabel` and a `JCheckBox` on it. How would I change the background of the `JCheckBox` so that it does not have a square around it which is different to the standard look of the `JMenuBar`.

I have tried the following code and have so far been unsuccessful

```
chkbtnSmartSize.setBackground(this.getBackground());
```

(On a different attempt)

```
chkbtnSmartSize.setBackground(lblSmartSize.getBackground());
```

Any help in accomplishing this would be grateful

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there are a few ways to do this.

The simplest way to do this would to be to remove the border and the background of the component. For example with this check box I should do

```
chkbtnSmartSize.setOpaque(false);
chkbtnSmartSize.setContentAreaFilled(false);
chkbtnSmartSize.setBorder(null);
chkbtnSmartSize.setFocusable(false);
```

Another way would be to change the background of the JMenuBar and then do the same for the check box.

```
Color color = Color.red; 
@Override //This Method changes the background colour of the JMenuBar
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(color);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);

}
...
chkbtnSmartSize.setBackground(color);
```

If you remove the background of the check box and change the color of the `JMenuBar` you do not need the line of code `chkbtnSmartSize.setBackground(color);`

Finally if you set the background of the `JComponent` to the same color of the background of the `JMenuBar` it will have the same affect as the first method did.